# Simple LCD countdown timer

Tags: lcd, debugging

I tried to modify the basic "hello-world" sketch for the LCD that is a part of the examples section in the IDE. I intended to make a countdown timer using the LCD.

The original code simply prints "Hello World" in the first line, and then makes use of the `millis()` function to print the time elapsed in the next line.

So I tried a simple modification to make it count *down* from 20. Instead of printing `millis()/1000` , I printed `20-millis()/1000`, and also added a `while()` to only print till `millis()<=20,000`. (so that it does not go beyond `00)`

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>


LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

void setup() {
  
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  
  lcd.print("time left");
}

void loop() {
  
  while(millis()<=20000){
    
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    
    lcd.print(20- millis() / 1000);
  }
  

}
```

It seemed to work till `10`. but instead of `9`, it printed `90`, and likewise `80,70..` for `8,7...`etc till `00`.

**How can I get rid of these extra zeros?**

Comment: `lcd.print(' ');`

Comment: where do I put this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> instead of `9`, it printed `90`

No, it didn't: it printed “9”. However, it did not *erase* the previous
value before printing “9”. Before printing the 9, the LCD had:

```
┌────────────────┐
│time left       │
│10              │
└────────────────┘
 ^cursor position
```

When you printed “9”, that character replaced the “1”, and you end up
seeing “90”.

The fix, as pointed out by Juraj, is to add a space after printing the
numbers.

An alternative is to prepend a space (or a zero), but only when the
number to be displayed is less that 10:

```cpp
int count = 20 - millis() / 1000;
if (count < 10)
    lcd.print(' ');  // alternatively: '0'
lcd.print(count);
```